# Convert to floating number in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a quick and easy way to convert a floating number, in MATHEMATICA?

For example:

```
234 = 0.230*10^0
1.234 = 0.234*10^1
45.342 = 0.45342*10^2
```

then apply addition, subtraction, etc.

For example `234 + 12.5` in floating point it would be 
`0.234*10^0 + 0.125*10^1` applying rounding to 2 digits 
`0.23*10^0 + 0.13*10^1`

I need a function that can convert any number to floating point

Thanks!

Comment: `1.234 = 0.234*10^1` doesn't make any mathematical (or Mathematica-l) sense to me.  What do you want to convert, from what, to what ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark 
I already clarify the question, but I just need to know if there is a function that does what I need

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark if it's the same, but I need it to apply rounded to n digits. For example `12.768343`  in floating point  `0.12768343*10^2`  applying rounding to 4 digits `0.1277*10^2`

Comment: I tried SetPrecision[0.12768343*10^2,4]  in Wolfram Alpha and got 12.77. I also tried SetPrecision[12.768343,4]  and got 12.77.

Comment: Let me know if you need any additional input. Mathematica and WA are friendly territory (I hope) for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following outputs its result as a string.  This may be the only way to get the format you want, e.g. `0.45342*10^2` because otherwise Mathematica will convert it to `45.342`.

```
g[x_] := Module[{},
  p = Floor[Log[10, N[x]]] + 1;
  StringJoin[ToString[N[x/10^p]],
   "*10^", ToString[p]]]

ans = g[45.342]
```

> 0.45342*10^2

Converting string to number.

```
ToExpression[ans]
```

> 45.342

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert to floating point. Wolfram Alpha will do whatever you need for you.

Comment: Sorry I meant Wolfram Mathematica.

Comment: @PeterSchaeffer then I will do operations with rounding to n digits, so I need it in floating point

Comment: sorry `1.234 = 0.1234*10^1`

Comment: I tried it again. 1.234 = 0.1234*10^1 yields True. I think SetPrecision and N should do what you need.

Comment: In my experience, Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica use  lots of digits. Generally you never have to worry about this. In C or C++ or Python 3 is an integer. In WA it is something more like 3.0000000000.

Comment: Let me know if you need any additional input. Mathematica and WA are friendly territory (I hope) for me.See my notes above about using SetPrecision[].